# Docker container not stopping

Tags: permissions, docker

What is the problem ?

```
root@hero:/home/intra# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                                            NAMES
b7f12c671a23        owasp/zap2docker-stable   "zap-webswing.sh"   25 minutes ago      Up 25 minutes (unhealthy)   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8090->8090/tcp   quizzical_bartik

root@hero:/home/intra# docker stop b7f12c671a23
Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: b7f12c671a23: Cannot kill container b7f12c671a23517a2c76c02e28a08af34fbe68a6709a09f5a303182656cb7c4d: unknown error after kill: runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:388: signaling init process caused "permission denied"
: unknown
root@hero:/home/intra#
```

Comment: Please run `ls -lah` in the directory in question and post back so we can see permissions of the Docker image.

Answer (score 7):

Initially I installed docker with snap, but encountered issues and completely removed it, and then installed with apt from docker repository. But it turned out I hadn't removed it completely.

Actually Ahmet did found the correct solution, I'm posting my answer just to show the formatted output for `sudo aa-remove-unknown`:

```
$ sudo aa-remove-unknown
Removing 'docker-default'
Removing 'snap-update-ns.docker'
Removing 'snap.docker.compose'
Removing 'snap.docker.docker'
Removing 'snap.docker.dockerd'
Removing 'snap.docker.help'
Removing 'snap.docker.hook.install'
Removing 'snap.docker.hook.post-refresh'
Removing 'snap.docker.machine'
```

Answer (score 4):

For me it was solved by running

```
sudo aa-remove-unknown
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
```

The first part was suggested here, the second part I found on another forum.

Answer (score 0):

It appears something has gotten into an invalid state, possibly a bug in dockerd, containerd, or runc. Upgrade to the current stable release and restart the docker daemon (typically `systemctl restart docker`).

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for this problem,use this command and later run docker kill for containers..

```
sudo aa-remove-unknown
```